# Doubts in using switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have a doubt: why am I getting outputs when `i=3` **and** when `i=7`?

```
main()
{
  int i;
  scanf("%d",&i);
  switch(i)
  {
        case 3: printf("message3");
        default:
               if(i==4)
               printf("message4");
        case 2:printf("message2");
               break;
        case 1:printf("Message1");
  }
}
```

Comment: removing the `C++` tag and placing `C` tag instead.

Comment: I think the program is pasted incorrectly. Pasted the same program twice in the switch statement after `case 1:`, I beleive. Post your comments if the modifications I make in it are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

i == 3 will print message3 and message2
 i == 4 will print message4 abd message2
 every other value of i will print message2

use `break` to terminate processing of a match.

Answer (score 2):

@Shubham. Please forgive me if I am repeating what you already know. And in some ways, I am expanding what @Henk already pointed out.

In `switch` statement, the role of `case` and `default` labels are only to determine where the execution should start. Once the first label is determined then rest of the labels have no meaning. The execution is "fall through". Therefore, we have to use `break` to stop and exit the `switch`.

In your code, if `i == 3` then `case 3` is the first line of execution. Then `case 3`, `default` and `case 2` are executed followed by `break`.

If `i` is any value other than `3` then `default` is executed followed by `case 2` and then exit the `switch`. I don't think one will ever get to execute `case 1` due to the location of  `default`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `break` after case 3 and `default`.

Answer (score 1):

After `case 3` there is no `break`. So, `switch` falls through and executes `default` statement too.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the `default` case does not determine when that case is executed. The `default` case is executed when the switch variable does not match any of the values in a case expression.

For the code above a value of

- `1` will print "Message 1" when executing the code following the `case 1`
- `2` will print "message 2" when executing the code following the `case 2`
- `3` will print "message 3message2" when executing the code following the `case 3` and **fallthrough** to `default` and **fallthrough** to `case 2`
- `4` will print "message 4message2" when executing the code following the `default` and **fallthrough** to `case 2`
- any other value will print "message 2" when executing the `default` case and **fallthrough** to `case 2`

---

I some times code my switches with the default first

```
switch (ch) {
  default: break; /* do nothing */
  case '.': ch = ','; break; /* swap commas */
  case ',': ch = '.'; break; /* and periods */
}
```